# How to write complex Sqlite SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

So, allow me to give an example. This is how the table looks like:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | body | date | type |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | foo  | 1101 | typ1 |
| 4  | baz  | 1110 | typ1 |
| 3  | bar  | 1115 | typ2 |
| 3  | goo  | 1114 | typ1 |
| 2  | fee  | 1111 | typ2 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

So I need to prepare a SELECT statement that returns something like this:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | body | date | type |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | foo  | 1101 | typ1 |
| 3  | goo  | 1114 | typ1 |
| 3  | bar  | 1115 | typ2 | <- this is here because date is greater than 1114
| 4  | baz  | 1110 | typ1 |
| 2  | fee  | 1111 | typ2 | <- this is here because date is greater than 1110
+----+------+------+------+
```

What's the sorting logic and what I have to keep in mind?

- `id` column is really not an ID. As you can see, `3` is repeated and the difference is the `type`.
- `typ1` must be sorted by ID ascending (in this case `date` does not matter).
- `typ2` must be merge into sorted `type1` by `date` (unix time).
- Sentence is passed to an already created method (let's suppose it's object.query("SELECT ... etc.")). So I'm not allowed to do this in multiple steps.

Do you have any ideas? Besides basic stuff like `SELECT ... ORDER BY id ASC` I haven't been able to think of a way of working this around.

#### Edit

This is how the sorted table was built:

1. You must order typ1 by ID:

.

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | body | date | type |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | foo  | 1101 | typ1 |
| 3  | goo  | 1114 | typ1 |
| 4  | baz  | 1110 | typ1 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Then we have to put typ2 ordered by date, with this constraints though:

- `typ2` must appear below the higher `typ1 date` which is not greater than the `typ2 date`.

Comment: Doing that does not work always... suppose, in the example above that id 2 is actually id 54. In that case, that record would appear at the end, and I still need it to be in the second row of the result set.

Comment: Hehe... here is basically the condition: typ1 must be ordered by ID, typ2 must be ordered by date (depending on how typ1 was ordered)

Comment: @Chistian: You say that *"typ1 must be ordered by ID"*, yet you put row with `id=4, type=typ1` at the end. Why?

Comment: @Cristian: My question is a bit similar to @ypercube's: how is it determined that the `id=3, type=typ2` row should follow `id=3, type=typ1` and not `id=4, type=typ1`? The date value of `1115` is greater than either `1114` or `1110`, so why should the order be like what is shown?

Comment: Just updated the question with a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT x.id,x.date, y.body,y.type from table as x left outer join table as y on (x.id=y.id) where 
x.date >1101 or x.date>1114`

---

I guess u want red values ?? am right

Comment: it can be : SELECT x.id,x.date, y.body,y.type from table as x left  join table as y on (x.id=y.id) where x.date >1101 or x.date>1114

Comment: But... it's just one table... would be that a problem?

Comment: @Cristian no problem using the "AS" clause will rename the table so it's like dealing with 2 tables at the same time .

Comment: Well... also, the table above was just an example. I don't know how many rows it could have (so it could be thousands) so I can't do `x.date > FOO or x.date > BAR or x.date`... etc.

Comment: Can u provide an sample of the real data , and how u want it to be displayed ?? u can use www.pastepin.com  to paste anything ...

Comment: Real data is just like the one I posted... the only difference is that instead of 5 rows there are thousands.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are going for. Can you try this and let me know if it does it?

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN type='typ1' THEN id 
        WHEN type='typ2' THEN (
            SELECT T1.id
            FROM TheTable AS T1 
            WHERE T1.date=(SELECT MAX(T2.date)
                           FROM TheTable AS T2
                           WHERE T2.type='typ1' AND T2.date<TheTable.date)
                AND T1.type='typ1')
    END AS order_by_value,
    id, body, date, type
FROM TheTable
ORDER BY order_by_value, type, date;
```

This will be problematic if there are 'typ2' records with dates smaller than the smallest 'typ1' date; otherwise it should work fine.

If you don't want the "order_by_value" column in your result set, subselect from the previous SQL query this way:

```
SELECT id, body, date, type 
FROM (
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN type='typ1' THEN id 
        WHEN type='typ2' THEN (
            SELECT T1.id
            FROM TheTable AS T1 
            WHERE T1.date=(SELECT MAX(T2.date)
                           FROM TheTable AS T2
                           WHERE T2.type='typ1' AND T2.date<TheTable.date)
                AND T1.type='typ1')
    END AS order_by_value,
    id, body, date, type
FROM TheTable
ORDER BY order_by_value, type, date);
```